# LWJGL builds with GitLab CI

Tags: java, lwjgl, gitlab-ci

I have been trying to get GitLab CI to build my LWJGL project with no luck, after about an hour of tinkering I have this as my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: java:8-jdk
buildtest:
 script:
 - mkdir bin
 - javac -cp dependencies/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar -d bin/ src/*.java
 - cd bin
 - java HelloWorld
```

However after finally getting it to compile correctly, when it comes time to run the code it gets the following log:

```
$ mkdir bin
$ javac -cp dependencies/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar -d bin/ src/*.java
$ cd bin
$ java HelloWorld
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFWKeyCallback
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more

ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

It seems to me that it cannot find `org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback`, however when compiled locally it works fine. So I cannot figure out what the issue is, any ideas?

EDIT:

After messing around with this some more, I ended up trying this on my machine and the following works in command prompt, but not in a shell script and because GitLab CI uses linux it does not work there either. 
Here is the shell script I wrote real quick to test along with the new error:

```
mkdir bin
javac -cp dependencies/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar -d bin/ src/*.java
cd bin
java -cp ../dependencies/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar; -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=../dependencies/lwjgl/native/ HelloWorld
```

Error (I know its the usage for java.exe, but it prints both that and the error at the end):

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-server       to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
bash: -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=../dependencies/lwjgl/native/: No such file or directory
```

I know for a fact that this directory exists though because I can get it to work in the following way with command prompt:

```
javac -cp dependencies/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar -d bin/ src/*.java
cd bin
java -cp ../dependencies/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar; -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=../dependencies/lwjgl/native/ HelloWorld
```

Output from command prompt version:

```
E:\test\bin>java -cp ../dependencies/lwjgl/lwjgl.jar; -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=../dependencies/lwjgl/native/ HelloWorld
Hello LWJGL 3.0.0b SNAPSHOT!

E:\test\bin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the library path to the folder containing the native files.

```
java -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=path/to/natives HelloWorld
```

You can find the files (which have endings `.so`, `.dylib` and `.dll`) in the `native` folder of the LWJGL zip file.

Comment: My native folder looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/77e6d0c087de31f5fed02049ea156be3) and I changed my .gitlab-ci.yml to look like this: `- java -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=dependencies/lwjgl/native/ HelloWorld` , however it still does not want to run correctly, I am getting the same error as above.

Comment: You cd into the `bin` directory beforehand, so the path should probably be `../dependencies/lwjgl/native/`.

Comment: Updated main post.